# Data viewing issue

Tags: r, view, dataframe

I'm running (trying to at least) a gibbs sampler in R and am having issues with viewing the data.

I am using R Studio

For reference here is my code:

```
###Step 2
###Draw from truncated normal
for(i in 1:length(cens.list[,1])){

  row.i <- as.numeric(cens.list[i,1])

  mu.i <- as.numeric(x.mat[row.i,] %*% beta)

  bio.set[row.i,var.name] <- rtnorm(1,mean=mu.i,sd=sqrt(var),lower=-Inf,upper=dl)
}

test <- bio.set[which(row.names(bio.set) %in% cens.list[,1]),]
```

bio.set contains my variable I'm trying to impute and other information

cens.list contains of list of the censored values to be imputed and their corresponding row information.

dl is a detection limit. The observations being imputed are missing due to falling below this value

The issue: When I try to view the data (using `View()` or `edit()`) the imputed values are all showing the same number (the detection limit). This happens whether I view them through the test data frame or through bio.set itself.

However, if I view the values individually by typing

```
bio.set[995,var.name] #Where I set the row number to be one of the imputed rows.
```

It shows me the correctly drawn values.

Can I proceed assuming that the data is correctly stored and it's just a viewer issue? Or is there something I'm doing incorrectly?

Comment: The number of possible sources of error remains large. Please post an example that defines all of the parameters that are currently unspecified.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO.  To help make a reproducible example, you can use   `reproduce(<your data>)` . Instructions are here: http://bit.ly/SORepro   -  [How to make a great R reproducible example](http://bit.ly/SORepro)

Comment: Post the update as a solution and accept it, I would suggest, that others see that it's a closed question. That way it's more use-full to the community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the replies. I was working on creating a reproducible example when I figured out what my issue was.

Basically what happened is that cens.list contains the row numbers of the values to be imputed. After it is created some rows are deleted for whatever reason but the previous row numbers are stored by R

In the code I presented, you can see within the loop I'm referencing the row number specific to the current state of the dataframe rather than the row.names.

To fix this I'm going to use an id variable, as I should have done all along.

In future questions I will make sure that my code is something that is reproducible.